# Events -VERSUS- Callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, callback, jquery-events

What is more reasonable/faster in JavaScript: using `callbacks()` or react to `events`?

**JavaScript: Callback**

```
doSomething(function(){
   //one or more callbacks (onSuccess, onError, etc)
});
```

**JavaScript: Event**

```
function initSomething(){
   //do something
   $(document).trigger('reactOnEvent');    
}

$(document).on('reactOnEvent', function(){
   //callback via event
});
initSomething();
```

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181007/javascript-events-vs-callbacks-in-mvc-scenario

Comment: What's 'more reasonable' is subjective. What's 'faster' is something you can test yourself. But which one you should choose depends on what you're trying to accomplish. Both are good but have different design implications: the event is global, while the callback needs to be provided every time you call `doSomething`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Events vs. Callbacks In MVC Scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181007/javascript-events-vs-callbacks-in-mvc-scenario)